# Where is Spark Skin Button Size Set?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex-spark

I've skinned an hSlider's thumb with an image. But the image is  pixelated, as though it's been forced to resize.  It's just a pretty circle with a radius of 30 px.

The other thing that happens is that instead of the new button being cleanly bisected by the track, it is just below the track, tangential to it. So now I have to reposition it by modifying its y value in SliderThumbSkin.mxml? And (presumably because its registration point is at upper left) when I slide it all the way to the right, it goes right off the end of the track until its left edge is at the track's right edge. This might also mess up calculations for the hSlider.value property.

You'd think you could just apply the skin and it would replace the button, but seems that both its position and size are being wrongly manipulated.Is the thumb's size automatically reset or resized somewhere?  Is there a way to do this correctly and cleanly?

EDIT: Here's code for the entire test project:

```
//HSliderTest.mxml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
firstView="views.HSliderTestHomeView" applicationDPI="160">
<fx:Declarations>
<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>

//SliderSkin.mxml. Only modified the <s:Button tag at the end:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minHeight="11"
alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[
/**
* @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
*/
[HostComponent("spark.components.HSlider")]

]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
/* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized.
For slider, the skin itself is colorized but the individual parts are
not. */

static private const exclusions:Array = ["track", "thumb"];

/**
* @private
*/
override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return
exclusions;}

/**
* @private
*/
override protected function initializationComplete():void
{
useChromeColor = true;
super.initializationComplete();
}
</fx:Script>

<fx:Script>
/**
* @private
*/
override protected function measure() : void
{
// Temporarily move the thumb to the left of the Slider so
measurement
// doesn't factor in its x position. This allows resizing the
// HSlider to less than 100px in width.
var thumbPos:Number = thumb.getLayoutBoundsX();
thumb.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, thumb.getLayoutBoundsY());
super.measure();
thumb.setLayoutBoundsPosition(thumbPos, thumb.getLayoutBoundsY());
}
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
<s:State name="normal" />
<s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<fx:Declarations>
<!--- The tooltip used in the mx.controls.Slider control.
To customize the DataTip's appearance, create a custom
HSliderSkin class.-->
<fx:Component id="dataTip">
<s:DataRenderer minHeight="24" minWidth="40" y="-34">
<s:Rect top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
<s:fill>
<s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha=".9"/>
</s:fill>
<s:filters>
<s:DropShadowFilter angle="90" color="0x999999"
distance="3"/>
</s:filters>
</s:Rect>
<s:Label id="labelDisplay" text="{data}"
horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5"
textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
fontWeight="normal" color="white" fontSize="11">
</s:Label>
</s:DataRenderer>
</fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<!--- The default skin class is HSliderTrackSkin.
@copy spark.components.supportClasses.TrackBase#track
@see spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin -->
<s:Button id="track" left="0" right="0" width="11" height="11"
tabEnabled="false"
skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin" />

<!--- The default skin class is HSliderThumbSkin.
@copy spark.components.supportClasses.TrackBase#thumb
@see spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin -->
<s:Button id="thumb" top="0" bottom="0" height="11" width="11"
tabEnabled="false" skinClass="skins.SliderThumbSkin" />
</s:SparkSkin>

//SliderThumbSkin.mxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkButtonSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
minWidth="21"
minHeight="21"
alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[
/**
* @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
*/
[HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
<s:State name="up" />
<s:State name="over" />
<s:State name="down" />
<s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>
<s:Image source.up="assets/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png"
source.over="assets/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png"
source.down="assets/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png"
source.disabled="assets/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png"
width="60"
height="60"/>
</s:SparkButtonSkin>
```

Can anyone see why this doesn't display correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer.

SliderSkin.mxml --

```
 //change this line
 thumb.setLayoutBoundsPosition(thumbPos, (thumb.getLayoutBoundsY() **- 25**));
 //and change this line too
 <s:Button id="thumb" **top="-25"** bottom="0" height="11" width="11"
```

So the whole class looks like this:

```
   @see spark.components.HSlider
   @see spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin
   @see spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin

  @langversion 3.0
  @playerversion Flash 10
  @playerversion AIR 1.5
  @productversion Flex 4
 -->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minHeight="11" alpha.disabled="0.5">

<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[ 
    /** 
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.HSlider")]

]]>
</fx:Metadata> 

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
       For slider, the skin itself is colorized but the individual parts are not. */

    static private const exclusions:Array = ["track", "thumb"];

    /**
     * @private
     */  
    override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        useChromeColor = true;
        super.initializationComplete();
    }
</fx:Script>

<fx:Script>
    /**
     *  @private
     */  
    override protected function measure() : void
    {
        // Temporarily move the thumb to the left of the Slider so measurement
        // doesn't factor in its x position. This allows resizing the
        // HSlider to less than 100px in width. 
        var thumbPos:Number = thumb.getLayoutBoundsX();
        thumb.setLayoutBoundsPosition(0, thumb.getLayoutBoundsY());
        super.measure();
        thumb.setLayoutBoundsPosition(thumbPos, (thumb.getLayoutBoundsY() - 25));
    }
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!--- The tooltip used in the mx.controls.Slider control. 
           To customize the DataTip's appearance, create a custom HSliderSkin class.-->
    <fx:Component id="dataTip">     
       <s:DataRenderer minHeight="24" minWidth="40" y="-34">  
          <s:Rect top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha=".9"/>
                </s:fill>
                <s:filters>
                    <s:DropShadowFilter angle="90" color="0x999999" distance="3"/>
                </s:filters>
            </s:Rect>
            <s:Label id="labelDisplay" text="{data}"
                     horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
                     left="5" right="5" top="5" bottom="5"
                     textAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                     fontWeight="normal" color="white" fontSize="11">
            </s:Label>
        </s:DataRenderer>
   </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<!--- The default skin class is HSliderTrackSkin. 
        @copy spark.components.supportClasses.TrackBase#track
        @see spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin -->
<s:Button id="track" left="0" right="0" width="11" height="11"
          tabEnabled="false"
          skinClass="spark.skins.spark.HSliderTrackSkin" />

<!--- The default skin class is HSliderThumbSkin.
        @copy spark.components.supportClasses.TrackBase#thumb 
        @see spark.skins.spark.HSliderThumbSkin -->
<s:Button id="thumb" top="-25" bottom="0" height="11" width="11"
          tabEnabled="false"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          skinClass="skins.SliderThumbSkin" />
```

SliderThumbSkin -- change s:Image  x="-25":

```
<fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
    /** 
    * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
    */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    ]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<!-- states -->
<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<s:Image  x="-25" source.up="@Embed('assets/buttons/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png')"
                         source.over="@Embed('assets/buttons/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png')"
                         source.down="@Embed('assets/buttons/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png')"
                         source.disabled="@Embed('assets/buttons/PurpleOnlyCircle60x60.png')"
         />
```